# Binding CornerRadius to Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, cornerradius

i want to bind the CornerRadius Values.

```
CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadiusInfoBtn}"
```

This is the code in TitleBar.

And this is my property.

```
        public CornerRadius CornerRadiusInfoBtn
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusInfoBtnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusInfoBtnProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CornerRadiusInfoBtn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusInfoBtnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadiusInfoBtn", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(TitleBar), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0)));
```

But there a no round corners. Whats wrong?

Comment: Where is round corners? Is it inside the CornerRadius class?

Comment: Are you setting the data context to an instance of `TitleBar`?

Comment: When I set a value above 0 the corners are rounded.

Comment: Property is in class `MainWindow` or `TitleBar`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the Property is in TitleBar

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I'm a newbie in xaml and c#. What do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Check output window of Visual Studio. There must be some binding errors over there.

Comment: @user3197157 Where is `DataContext` being set? Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared your `DependencyProperty` in the `TitleBar.xaml.cs` file, then your `TitleBar.xaml` file should contain a `Border` declared like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadiusInfoBtn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:TitleBar}}, Mode=OneWay}}" ... />
```

You either need to set the `DataContext` property to itself (which is not advised except for quick demonstrations), or use a `RelativeSource Binding` such as that above to locate the property.